# how to do a word wrap on a short string with TextLayout in java Graphics2d?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d, word-wrap

How would you effectively do a word wrap on a short label String below with TextLayout in java?

My label are only two or three words long
Some examples: 
1. Inflatable Greenhouse D10 ; 
2. Command and Control Center A5; 
3. Jason Boris;

I'd like to wrap the words in such a way to shape as like a square as possible, rather than one long rectangle.

So my question is: What does it take to wrap the building names to the 2nd line, instead of one long line? See pic below:

[image: overlapping names]

Is there a way to set the maximum number of characters to be contained in a line of text and wrap the remaining characters to the second line and so on (it would need to account for whitespace)?

For example, I'd like to wrap the name "Residential Quarter D12" into three lines.

```
  Residential
   Quarter
     D12
```

and wrap "Command and Control D16" into four lines.

```
 Command 
   and
 Control
   D16
```

Wouldn't it be nice if TextLayout can understand html codes like a regular JLabel!? Then it'll make things easy:

```
       String label = "<html>" + "Inflatable" + "<br>" + "Greenhouse"  + "<br>" + "D10" + "</html>";
```

Note: it doesn't have to be one word per line. But I'd like to have them "centered" on each line

What I have was the following method for generating a BufferedImage of the building name labels o or just the first and last name of a person.

```
    private BufferedImage createLabelImage(
    String label, Font font, FontRenderContext fontRenderContext, Color labelColor, 
    Color labelOutlineColor) {

    // Determine bounds.
    TextLayout textLayout1 = new TextLayout(label, font, fontRenderContext);
    Rectangle2D bounds1 = textLayout1.getBounds();

    // Get label shape.
    Shape labelShape = textLayout1.getOutline(null);

    // Create buffered image for label.
    int width = (int) (bounds1.getWidth() + bounds1.getX()) + 4;
    int height = (int) (bounds1.getHeight()) + 4;
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Get graphics context from buffered image.
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bufferedImage.getGraphics();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.translate(2D - bounds1.getX(), 2D - bounds1.getY());

    // Draw label outline.
    Stroke saveStroke = g2d.getStroke();
    g2d.setColor(labelOutlineColor);
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
    g2d.draw(labelShape);
    g2d.setStroke(saveStroke);

    // Fill label
    g2d.setColor(labelColor);
    g2d.fill(labelShape);

    // Dispose of image graphics context.
    g2d.dispose();

    return bufferedImage;
}
```

As you can see, this method can only create a BufferedImage form of label with one line of text only.

As I overlay these BufferedImage labels on a map, they look too long and they overlap one another.

That's why I need to make each label to shape like a square as possible.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a square image which contains centered text, which if wrapped, wraps with an even amount of characters as possible on each line?

Comment: yes you spoke my mind. I just edited my questions and posted a pic of what I had. thx for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to suggest an algoritm.

Split the label by space to get list of words and measure each word to get array

```
int[] wordWidths;
int minWidth=max(wordWidths);
int height=the row height const;
int minHeight=height;
int maxHeight=wordWidths.length*height;

int currentWidth=minWidht;
int currentHeight=maxHeight;

while(currentWidth<currentHeight || wordWidths.length>1) {
  int mergedWidth=find minimal sum of neighbour words' widths
  replace the 2 widths with the mergedWidth reducing the wordWidthssize
  currentHeight=wordWidths.length*height;
}
```

Or you can try to rely on components. I would define a `JTextArea` instance assigning the label there and trying to play with the wrap reducing width 1 by 1 and measuring preferred height for the width.
When optimal size is achived you can call `theWrappedJtextArea.printAll(g)` to paint it on your `BufferedImage's` `Graphics`.

Comment: can you break down further? appreciate!